# Docker container in-app port forwarding

Tags: python, docker, iptables, portforwarding

I actually trying to make port forwarding for Docker which make request to mysql database on a remote server.

My goal is to create a copy of an app production in a container which can has access to an existent MySQL server based on a remote one.

I create a Dockerfile with all the requirements embedded, as follow :

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

mkdir /working_env

RUN apk add --update mysql\
                mysql-client\
                python-dev\
                build-base \
                && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Requirements here
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKSPACE working_env

COPY init.sh .

# BIND TO 8053
RUN init.sh start
```

and run this container with a volume mapped to the local project

```
docker run --name --rm project -v $(pwd):/working_env -d -p 8053:8053 project_docker
```

the call is made in my code as follows :

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=10.11.12.13, port=3000, passwd=foo, user=admin, db=default)
```

But I want to be able when the call is made from inside my container, that it's been replaced from `10.11.12.13:3000` to `10.11.12.13:3001`.

I've found topics about `iptables` and tries to create rules, but all my tries have failed in order to forward this port.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j REDIRECT --to 3001
```

Does it even possible to made this kind of modification or is it a another way to alter the port from inside the docker?

Comment: why not set up an environment/application variable "$MY_REMOTE_DB" which is being set on docker build ?

Comment: @Yerken Good idea but I don't want alterate my code. If i understand well I need to use this ENV and bind it to my code.